# Paycheck withdraw

Tags: company

I got paid from a Amazon company last week for a total of 350* from working the previous week which was the week of Christmas . I did not show up for the rest of that since i was out in Mexico with no way to contact them. I looked at my account today to realize that they reversed my paycheck . Which was a week later from when i got payed. I’m gonna wait a few days to see if they did a error. Are they allowed to do that or is that a red flag?

Comment: The fact that the company is able to pull money out of your bank account suggests to me that you are in America. Can you please confirm.

Comment: And did you check your contract? Did you violate it when you simply stopped attending work? What remedies, if any, are specified in the contract for such an occurance?

Comment: How did you end up in Mexico with no way to communicate?  Surely you could have sent a message before leaving on your trip??

Comment: Whether they are allowed to do it is a matter for a lawyer that has access to your specific contract. Is it a red flag? Well, it certainly fits well for a company that has it's employees just ghost them running of to a foreign country. I guess you two deserve each other, flag parade and all.

Comment: What exactly is that, when you stated, "rest of that"?  Are you talking about the week of Christmas or the following week?

Comment: The timeline you've given is very unclear. Are you saying that you were paid for time worked and then they took the money back in retaliation because you didn't show up for scheduled work later **or** that you were paid, at least in part, for work you didn't do because you were away? Can you please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what occurred?

Answer (score 4):

So, in the USA, employers are allowed to reverse transactions made to bank accounts in the case of over-payment.

My guesses:

1. They have a clause to recoup training costs if you leave before a certain date
2. You left before a certain date
3. They are using that clause to recoup some of their costs associated with training you

Do I find it a red flag? Yes, both your behaviour and their behaviour is a red flag. I wouldn't hire an employee that just went missing, and I wouldn't work for an employer that reversed payment.

Whether it's legal or not is a completely separate matter, one which you'll have to analyse your work contract and various regulations to determine. For instance, I would have been surprised ultimately the net result is that you worked under USA federal minimum wage.